# How to find the immediate parent of the derived class

Tags: c++

Suppose I have a base class B, derived class D, derived derived class DD.
How can I get the instance of the immediate parent to my current object?

e.g.

```
DD dd;
if (condition )
  dd->myfunction();
else
  d = getcurrentparent(); // this should give the current parent, here D d;
```

Edit:

Ok I am adding my scenario.

Its like an Menu. And each menu is different class.

main menu - base class
sub menu - derived class
sub sub menu - derived derived class.

Now when I am traversing in the sub sub menu, I need to know the immediate parent of the current obj (like going back from sub sub menu to sub menu)

Comment: I'm confused by the name `getcurrentparent()`.  A class hierarchy is a static thing -- it doesn't change at runtime for particular instances -- so what is the word "current" doing in there?

Comment: I'm not sure this makes much sense as is. If you wrote DD, you know that D is its parent. (It's also not well defined with multiple inheritance.) Could you provide a "real" use-case describing what exactly you're trying to achieve?

Comment: What does _"the instance of the immediate parent"_ actually mean? You could perhaps get -an- instance of the superclass, but there's no language-defined notion of a parent _instance_, only a parent _type_.

Comment: you are trying to traverse through a hierarchy of **Objects**. NOT classes. A class is just a prototype of an Object. the question should be how to get the parent object. for example: when your menu item `MyPictures` could be an object of "sub_menu" class. the parent of the `MyPictures` is `MyDocuments`. But `MyDocuments` is an object of the `main_menu` class. So when you call a function like `MyPictures->getParent()` it returns a pointer to the `MyDocuments` **Object**. This is what you want... Rite??

Comment: exactly like MainMenu contain MyDocument, MyPicture. And MyDocument contain OfficeDoc and PersonalDoc. I need to know that my immediate parent is MyDocument, when I am inside the personalDoc,

Comment: I think you mean "contains" instead of "is the parent class of".  These are very different things -- it doesn't make sense to derive a MyDocument class from a MainMenu class, but it might well make sense to have a MainMenu class whose objects contain MyDocument objects, or pointers or references to them.

Answer (score 2):

If you have `DD dd;`, you can always get a reference to any of its base classes just by assigning to a reference:

```
DD dd;
D& d = dd;
```

I'm not sure why you would want to do this though, as a derived object can do everything that the base object can do (and more).

Comment: I think the question is about finding which class is the parent

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this,

```
class D : public B
{
   virtual const char * GetParent()
   {
       return "B";
   }

    // other stuff....
}

class DD : public D
{
   virtual const char * GetParent()
   {
       return "D";
   }

   // other stuff....
}
```

I Hope this is what you want. Why do you need such a thing? are you creating something like an object registry with a hierarchy or something similar?

--EDIT--

`D * d = &dd;`
or if you really want,
create a copy function which copies DD objects to D objects.
But what i guess is that you are not asking your question correctly.

p.s. sorry that i read the question wrongly the first time.

--EDIT--

Ok, What you need is Composite Design Pattern. Its not very complex as the UML diagram shows. Once you implement it, its really easy to code your other stuff. When talking about design patterns, I like the book "Design Patterns for Dummies". It explains the design patterns very nicely and it has explained the Composite Design pattern very well. If you need help in it put a comment asking. but first try to do it yourself. :) enjoy.
Wikipedia Link : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern

--EDIT--
Composite DP is like this,
[image: Composite Design Pattern]

assuming your scenario is a very simple menu on the console, i would do it like this,

- `Leaf` ==> `MenuItem` class
- `Composite` ==> `Menu` class
- `+operation()` ==> `Select()` function of the both classes. This function should be virtual and overridden in the `Menu` class and `MenuItem` class to *display/expand* and *select item* respectively.
- `Menu` class will have functions to `GoBack()` to parent menu

Comment: Is it possible to have multiple inheritance using this ?

Comment: Of course. Design Patterns are just guide lines. They are not rules or anything. You should change it according to your need. :) Always have a good design that will make your work easy.

Answer (score 1):

Not a good idea. You can do what was suggested above but that's not a good design choice. Besides, what parent do you want in case of multiple inheritance(or multiple interfaces)?